# What did I do wrong in this simple related rates problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

The question is

> A street light is mounted at the top of a 15-ft-tall pole. A man  6 ft tall walks away from the pole with a speed of 5 ftys along a straight path. How fast is the tip of his shadow moving when he is 40 ft from the pole?

I drew a diagram like this to model the situation:
[image]

Where $x$ is the distance between the pole and the man, and $y$ is the length of the shadow of the man. I'm pretty sure the question is asking to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ when $x=40$,  so I expressed $y$ in terms of $x$.
$$
\frac{15}{6}=\frac{x+y}{y} \Rightarrow y=\frac{2}{3}x
$$
I tried using the chain rule to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$

We're given that the man is walking at $5 \text{ ft/s}$ so $x$ is increasing at a rate of $5 \text{ft/s}$, therefore, $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$. To find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we simply differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$.
$$
y=\frac{2}{3}x \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{3}
$$

So it follows that since $\frac{dx}{dt}=5$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}$ must be
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = 5\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{10}{3} \text{ ft/s}
$$

Except that it isn't. The correct answer in the textbook I'm using states that it is in fact $\frac{25}{3} \text{ ft/s}$. I'm just confused about where I went wrong! This was my entire process to get to the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the textbook is looking for how fast the tip of the shadow is moving relative to the pole, not to the man, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)= \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}= 5\text{ft/s} + \frac{10}{3}\text{ft/s} = \frac{25}{3}\text{ft/s}.$$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense!